# loop through quantiles to create unique column in dataset

Tags: r, for-loop

I currently have a dataset with ages and CPUE. I need to make a loop (or other code) to

1. subset the data frame into unique data frames
2. for each unique age, find the percentile value from 10 to 90 by 1% for CPUE
3. add each percentile CPUE value to the dataset (whether subsetted by age or identified by age) as a new column
4. add another column based on the threshold of cpue that would be similar to an ifelse statement where the column would tell you if the cpue threshold was met or not.

The code I have so far is non-looped and appears as follows:

```
    #####subsetting for each age
    yr1=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==1),]
    yr2=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==2),]
    yr3=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==3),]
    yr4=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==4),]
    yr5=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==5),]
    yr6=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==6),]
    yr7=ycsnew[which(ycsnew$age==7),]

    ####creating a vector using for example the 80th percentile (I would like 
    this to be continuous from 0.1 to 0.9 by 0.01)
    q1=quantile(yr1$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q2=quantile(yr2$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q3=quantile(yr3$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q4=quantile(yr4$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q5=quantile(yr5$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q6=quantile(yr6$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]
    q7=quantile(yr7$logcpueplus1,0.8)[[1]]

   ####using ifelse statement to create column for probability greater than
   or equal to percentile value (pgtq8=ProbabilityGreaterThanQ80)
   yr1$pgtq8=ifelse(yr1$logcpueplus1>=q1,1,0)
   yr2$pgtq8=ifelse(yr2$logcpueplus1>=q2,1,0)
   yr3$pgtq8=ifelse(yr3$logcpueplus1>=q3,1,0)

  ##then I ended up binding everything back together
  ycsnew2=rbind(yr1,yr2,yr3,yr4,yr5,yr6,yr7)
```

I began the process of looping myself, and have gotten this far:

```
    ###1 subset into different year datasets
    age_split=split(ycsnew,ycsnew$age)
    new_names <- c("one", "two", "three","four","five","six","seven")
    for (i in 1:length(age_split)) {
      assign(new_names[i], age_split[[i]])
    }

    ###for each age, loop through to get values for 0.1-0.9 by0.01
    N=(seq(0.1,0.9,0.01))
    one_percentiles=matrix(rep("puppy",81),nrow=81,ncol=1)
    sequence1=c(seq(0.1,0.9,0.01))
    for(n in unique(seq(1,81,1))){
      for(i in sequence1){
       ps=quantile(one$logcpueplus1,i)[[1]]
       one_percentiles[[n]]=ps

         }
    }
```

I am now getting stuck because the "i" value is not looping through the "sequence1" object correctly and I simply get a "one_percentiles" matrix filled with the quantile value for only i=0.1 or i=0.9.

I will definitely be stumped with adding the ifelse() statement through a loop onto the dataset as a new column as well, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

My dataset is below.

```
logcpueplus1 age
1     0.13353139   7
2     0.13353139   6
3     0.06899287   2
4     0.08004271   1
5     0.13353139   6
6     0.06899287   7
7     0.04879016   4
8     0.04879016   4
9     0.13353139   7
10    0.06899287   7
12    0.06899287   6
13    0.06899287   2
14    0.06899287   2
15    0.06899287   7
16    0.06899287   6
17    0.09531018   4
21    0.13353139   7
22    0.18232156   4
24    0.04879016   4
25    0.09531018   4
26    0.06899287   2
28    0.06899287   7
30    0.04879016   4
37    0.08004271   1
39    0.04879016   4
40    0.08004271   1
41    0.13353139   6
42    0.25131443   6
43    0.13353139   7
44    0.04879016   4
47    0.08004271   1
49    0.04879016   4
50    0.13353139   5
52    0.19415601   6
53    0.13353139   7
54    0.19415601   6
55    0.30538165   5
56    0.04879016   3
57    0.06899287   1
59    0.06899287   6
60    0.35667494   5
61    0.09531018   3
63    0.19415601   6
64    0.25131443   5
65    0.09531018   3
66    0.06899287   6
67    0.19415601   6
69    0.06899287   1
70    0.13976194   3
71    0.13353139   5
73    0.04879016   3
77    0.06899287   6
78    0.04879016   3
79    0.06899287   7
```

Comment: I don't follow all your percentile stuff. Can you pick a single value of `age`, say `age = 1`,  and show the result you want for that age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using and fit all of my needs.

```
ycsB=ycsnew
dim(ycsnew)
names(ycsB)
see2=(seq(0.1,0.9,0.01))

ycsB[, 21:(21+length(see2)-1)]=NA
names(ycsB)
ages=unique(ycsnew$age)

for(s in 1:length(see2)){

   quant_name=see2[s]

for(b in 1:length(ages)){

  age_subset=subset(ycsB, ycsB$age==ages[b])
  age_quantile= quantile(age_subset$logcpueplus1,quant_name)

   ycsB[which(ycsB$age==ages[b]), (26+s)]=age_quantile
    for(j in 1:length(ages)){

      if_s=ifelse(age_subset$logcpueplus1>=age_quantile,1,0)  
      ycsB[which(ycsB$age==ages[b]), (107+s)]=if_s
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and where `df` is your dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(age) %>%
    mutate(q = quantile(logcpueplus1,0.8),
           pgtq8 = ifelse(logcpueplus1 >= q,1,0))
df
#Source: local data frame [54 x 4]
#Groups: age [7]
#    logcpueplus1   age          q      pgtq8
#    <dbl>          <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#1    0.13353139     7      0.13353139     1
#2    0.13353139     6      0.19415601     0
#3    0.06899287     2      0.06899287     1
#4    0.08004271     1      0.08004271     1
#5    0.13353139     6      0.19415601     0
#6    0.06899287     7      0.13353139     0
#7    0.04879016     4      0.09531018     0
#8    0.04879016     4      0.09531018     0
#9    0.13353139     7      0.13353139     1
#10   0.06899287     7      0.13353139     0
# ... with 44 more rows
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, if I had enough points I would vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, q := quantile(logcpueplus1, 0.8), age
          ][, pgtq8 := as.integer(logcpueplus1 >= q)][]
```